# How to give height to the ghost Image of HTML draggable element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, web

I am building an appointment calendar where one can book slots and drag / drop the slots to change time. Each slot is draggable HTML elements. But I found an issue when we try to drag slots that are small, the preview div or the ghost image (I don't know if it's the technical term) is showing some part of the next slots. In the below image, there are 4 different slots. When I try to drag the first slot (Green in color) some parts of the second slot are also shown in the ghost image.

My guess is that ghost image size has some min-height property and can be controlled? I could be wrong and I appreciate pointers that can help me fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to help you without seeing the actual code.

Maybe you're dragging the wrong element, maybe there's a mistake in what you're actually cloning to show the "ghost image" or maybe something else entirely.

If everything is correct and it still happens it's probably something to do with the css of your element. But again, without seeing any code this is just a guess.

If you want a quick solution simply set a fixed height (as tall as the one element you're dragging) to your ghost element and set its overflow property to hidden. It works, but I'd rather throw myself off a cliff than actually solving the problem like that.

I can gladly try to help you if you make a jsfiddle.